# Yajra Laravel Datatable column sorting and searching not working when serverside mode

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-7, yajra-datatable

try to use laravel datatables for serverside using laravel datatables by yajra,, data loaded perfectly but one of my column (the status column/ columns[2]) not sortable and not searchable, it's contain boolen data.

below is my code to load the table:

```
 let table = $('#simpleTable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            responsive: false,
            dom: '<"d-flex justify-content-between"pf>t', //default is 'lftipr'
            pagingType: 'simple',
            ajax: "{{ route('cabangs.index') }}",
            columns: [{
                    data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    name: 'DT_RowIndex'
                },
                {
                    data: 'nama_cabang',
                    name: 'nama_cabang',
                },
                {
                    data: 'is_open',
                    name: 'status',
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
            ]
        });
```

below is the response in console :

```
    2   Object { data: "is_open", name: "status", searchable: "true", … }
    data    "is_open"
    name    "status"
    searchable  "true"
    orderable   "true"
    search  Object { regex: "false", value: null }
```

notice that column serching and ordering is allready true,

```
    order   [ {…} ]
    0   Object { column: "2", dir: "asc" }
    column  "2"
    dir "asc"
    start   "0"
    length  "10"
    search  Object { regex: "false", value: null }
    value   null
    regex   "false"
    _   "1600576921782"
```

but when I set

```
processing: false,
serverside: false
```

the status column sorting and searching working fine

System details

```
OS = Windows 10
PHP =7.4.8
Laravel 7
Laravel-Datatables Version = "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
```